# Cannot find module 'node'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run a test script through package.json,

```
"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc mocha --recursive --compilers js:babel-register --require babel-polyfill",
```

and on running I get the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\aw030085\Desktop\github\diabetesdashboard\node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

I have a coworker who can run it just fine, but he's not sure if he has anything extra installed. I'm not sure why it's throwing an error.

I have node 10.16.2 installed, using Windows 10.

Comment: Do you know if node has been added to ```PATH```? - Assuming you're on Windows

Comment: @S.Ramjit yes, it's on my system path as C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

Comment: Are you user aw030085? or this is just a route that makes sense on your coworker computer

Comment: @PabloRecalde yes, I am user aw030085

Comment: you can always try deleting your node_modules and package-lock.json and then run npm install again.

Comment: @Jake that did it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

You can run this

```
npm uninstall nyc
npm i --save-dev nyc
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem and the given solution worked

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but if anyone has that problem, try lowering your node version.
This is what worked for my teammate in one of our projects